# Where is the java folder for libraries on linux

Tags: java, linux

I need to find \jre\lib\ext under the java folder to add libraries. And I am not sure how to find it

Comment: *"to add libraries"*  Don't do that. Add them to the run-time class-path of each app. that needs them.

Comment: I also need to add a shared library to /jre/lib/[machine type]

Comment: Still don't do it.  Andrew is right.  Only JARs from Oracle/Sun that extend the JDK belong there.  Nothing of yours should ever end up in that folder.

Comment: Don't JCE providers (like BouncyCastle) recommend putting their jars in `/jre/lib/ext`?  Or was that just a Java 1.4 thing?

Comment: Don't much care what a vendor would recommend.  "ext" means "extending the JVM" to me.  I think only Sun/Oracle should do that.

Comment: I don't think you should use ext lightly, but Oracle doesn't seem to agree that they are the only ones to add extensions:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/index.html

"Since this mechanism extends the platform's core API, its use should be judiciously applied. Most commonly it is used for well standarized interfaces such as those defined by the Java Community Process, although it may also be appropriate for site wide interfaces."

And one of the sections in that trail is called "Creating and Using Extensions".

Comment: Note that support for the extensions classloader and "lib/ext" was removed in Java 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String extDir = System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs");` to get the extensions dir path as you want (more info about system properties can be found [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/io/30properties_and_preferences/40sysprops/10sysprop.html)), set the path and write the jar files to that directory (be carefull to capture any IOException that could be raise in the writing process because this folders are usually write-protected or require root/admin privileges)

As quoted in the comments, this is something that should only be done in exceptional cases

Answer (score 2):

As most comments say don't do so, the alternative.

Most applications have an *app*.jar and a lib folder in which all library jars reside. In the application jar there is a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF with a class path including the lib jars.

As a developer I use maven (like ant, ivy) for the build infra structure and it does it just so. The jars are taken from the local maven repository else from the remote ones. Also maven uses a local repository of all jars in different versions. Jars missing in the remote repositories, like own programming, can be installed there.

BTW **/usr/lib/jvm/** contains the java versions (do `which java`, `which javac`).