# JNI library missing

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to run a test file InspectVM from libguestfs library inorder to have accesss to a disk image in windows. However, I have the following errors on my console

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no guestfs_jni in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at madjava.com.redhat.et.libguestfs.GuestFS.<clinit>(GuestFS.java:51)
    at madjava.examples.InspectVM.main(InspectVM.java:30)
C:\Users\CyberSOFONET\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)#
```

I searched allover the internet and find that I should set java.libraly.path pointing to location of the guestfs_jni. my major problem is that I do not have any file with that name guestfs_jni. Do I need to make one myself or can I find it somewhere. any kind of help is appriciated. am a newbie in JNI so I dont have much imformation on it

Comment: put your library in `<JRE_HOME>/lib/ext` folder. When you use a native programming interface either they should provide a JNI library or you should make it using java native support ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My library is not a jar file and I navigated to the folder you mentioned above, there are only jar files, should I just paste my library folder there? also would you mind telling me how I can make a JNI library using native support ecosystem. Thanks

Comment: Hi am failing to put my library in <JRE_HOME>/lib/ext folder because I can not locate the direcory similar to that You mentioned. am now using Ubuntu Linux, can you help me with steps on how I can achieve this...

Comment: You should first find out where your java installation is located. It is possible that you have OpenJDK by default along with an Oracle distributed JDK. If so first try to remove the OpenJDK completely. Using `echo $JAVA_HOME` find out where your JDK is located. After that you will find a JRE directory there and under JRE directory you can find the `/lib/ext` directory.

Comment: Also this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855492/where-is-the-java-folder-for-libraries-on-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a file called `guestfs_jni.dll`. Usually the native library comes with the jar file.

From http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-java.3.html:

> Libguestfs for Java is a Java Native Interface (JNI) extension, supplied in three parts: libguestfs.jar, libguestfs-VERSION.jar, libguestfs_jni.so, libguestfs.so

So the distribution comes with `libguest_jni.so` which ist for Linux and not for Windows. IIRC, there is no libguestfs for Windows. So you would first have to find out if it is even possible to compile libguestfs using Cygwin and if yes build it yourself.

If you're on Windows 10 you could try installing libguestfs and a Java runtime for the Linux subsystem and run inside the subsystem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. am on windows 10 and developing my project in netbeans . I will try the last option you stated

Comment: I switched to linux since I was only able to find .so JNI files from libguestfs. I tried I tried to add the java.library.path as follows